# How to put a string of text in csv file in 1 cell from $_POST

Tags: php

As the title explains, how to put a string of text in csv file in 1 cell from $_POST?

that's the code i'm using, and it puts 1 word in 1 cell instead of a string in 1 cell:

```
$file = 'itemlist.csv';
$name = $_POST["prod_name"];
file_put_contents($file, $name . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: @meda I mean an excel cell in column A which is A1. I need to be able to put a string in A1 in csv, because at the moment the result I'm getting of trying to insert a string of 5 words into A1 is this: first word = A1; second word = A2, third word = A3.

Comment: oohhh ok please show how your csv look and also the POST Value

Comment: @meda $_POST['prod_name'] = Product 1 but that obviously comes from a form, so I can't assign any value to it as the value is decided by a user who fills the form. The CSV file is empty, I just need to put whatever a user filling out the form in A1 in the CSV file.

Comment: @EvP, tell me if my solution help you

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to question titles, just accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_POST["prod_name"]="string wich have five words";
$file = 'itemlist.csv';
$name[] = $_POST["prod_name"];

$file = fopen($file, 'a');
fputcsv($file, $name );
fclose($file);
```

it will add, in `itemlist.csv`, first row/column the string in `$_POST["prod_name"]`

**EDIT**
in order to work with more $_POST variable, 12 or more:

```
  $file = 'itemlist.csv';
  foreach($_POST as $string) {
    $name[] = $string;
  }

  $file = fopen($file, 'a');
  fputcsv($file, $name );
  fclose($file);
```

Comment: i know, the first line is an example, remove it and test the code

Comment: any idea on how to put a second form field to B1? Thanks

Comment: sure, re execute the code... tell me how much $_POST variables do you have, in order to help you

Comment: 12 total. i think ill need to create an array here, right? thanks for the help

Comment: please, edit your question with more information, and how do you want your csv file,  and yes, fputcsv function use arrays